# Is it legal to use the APIs of Meetup.com, Eventbrite etc, to aggregate their event data into one place, similar to Google?

Tags: web-crawlers, web-development, legal, scraper-sites, aggregators

I have a predicament.  I'm trying to build a platform that will basically be a place where all events, online/offline, are listed.

Initially - my platform will obviously have zero events, because nobody knows about it.  And for anyone to use it - there needs to be events on there - classic chicken and egg scenario.

My thought was to aggregate events on to my platform (and link to their source), whilst also allowing users to create events on MY platform.  Eventually, I'd be able to not bother listing events from other sources if mine gains enough traction.  So, I am definitely competing with these sites.

Google is pulling data from many different events sources, and displaying it on their pages like so - https://www.google.com/search?q=events+in+london+meetup&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUA720GB740&oq=events+&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l3j69i60l3j69i65l2.4289j1j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&ibp=htl;events&rciv=evn&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiYtuPx2bLuAhU3REEAHaRkCZ0Q5rwDKAJ6BAgNEA4&sxsrf=ALeKk03Uj9jeI8lTj0__V-UWcgcv_pdFew:1611427139353#htivrt=events&htidocid=L2F1dGhvcml0eS9ob3Jpem9uL2NsdXN0ZXJlZF9ldmVudC8yMDIxLTAyLTAzfDE2ODA2NzEwNzgyNjAxNDg4MTQ2&fpstate=tldetail

The difference is, Google, I assume (?), is probably scraping the data rather than using APIs.

In the Meetup API Terms, it states:-

> "Not use the Meetup API for any commercial purpose without the express written consent of Meetup;

> Not undermine our commercial interests or make unreasonable commercial uses of the Meetup API, such as by substantially replicating our Platform or significant aspects of the Platform, to be determined in Meetup’s sole discretion;

> While you may charge for any application you develop (subject to Meetup’s consent), you may not sell, lease, or sublicense the Meetup API;"

I know aggregating is a bit of a legal grey area but I wanted to ask for opinions on whether or not this would be legal, and if not - how the hell do I get any traction and users without having any content?

Note: This is in the UK.

Comment: For legal questions, please state your jurisdiction. Thanks.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister- edited, it's in the UK.

Comment: Have you asked a lawyer?

Comment: Have you read their terms of use to see what they have to say about it?

Comment: @Steve - I'm trying to determine if I need a lawyer to get an answer.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - my post contains the snippet from their terms of use which I'm concerned about.

Answer (score 1):

For meetup.com It is a grey area, and probably against their terms and conditions. I'm not sure it matters that much though as the remedy they list is that they can withdraw your access, which they claim they can do for any reason any way.

With respect of Event Bright you are breaking their terms of service - they claim you may not "use the Eventbrite APIs in, or to develop, a product or service that competes with products or services offered by Eventbrite."

Depending on how serious you are, what your backing is like and how big you are/intend to get you might or might not want to consider if and how you can make yourself judgement proof, what your plan B is when API access is pulled and where you stand with respect of disruptors breaking the law to gain a foothold.  (eg Ubers business model)